# Android Radio Button not invisible or uncheck

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments

I use Sherlock fragment in my android and i add code to unchecked in invisible my radio button when fragment.
I use check box to show radio button and the problem is here when i make radio button visible and change fragment and again back to this fragment (as I said before I add code to Invisible and unchecked radio button) but the radio button not being invisible and even not being unchecked.

The Code that I used in onCreateView() for my fragment is:

```
chb_week.setChecked(false);
chb_week.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
rbtn_week_even.setChecked(false);
rbtn_week_odd.setChecked(false);
rbtn_week_even.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
rbtn_week_odd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

I can't find any problem i add them after any View installation.
and i say there is no error I Invisible more thing like button and spinners they are all worked but this code won't I don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're navigating back to the Fragment most probably is not created again, that would be why the code in onCreateView() is not executed.
Try to put that same code in onResume() instead:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        chb_week.setChecked(false);
        chb_week.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        rbtn_week_even.setChecked(false);
        rbtn_week_odd.setChecked(false);
        rbtn_week_even.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        rbtn_week_odd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```